# Is Bun really ~3 times faster than nodejs?

Tags: javascript, performance, runtime, bun

I was looking at [Bun Official Site](https://bun.sh/) there i noticed that they are claiming, bun is nearly 3 times faster than nodejs.
Is it really true or it is just a marketing strategy to promote bun over nodeJS?

[image: Bun comparison with nodejs]

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This is not the thing to worry about. Bun is only ten months old, isn't particularly established, and has no developers working on it other than Jared. I don't want to be hasty or mean but it sounds like a vanity project, and certainly not something I'd want to use right now. Are you having issues with (apparently) node's inadequate 16K+ HTML request p/s?

Comment: uWebSocets in github is 12x faster than NodeJS. So it is possible to be between 12x and 1x. But this speed difference diminishes once the content grows.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do bun install in my CRA react app for checking bun's performance

```
bun install v0.1.4
   @sentry/react [1608/1608]
```

it's maybe faster than node, but I think its not yet ready for everyday/production use.

*maybe I am with WSL (Ubuntu) coz of that its not always working properly for me*

Answer (score 0):

I did quite some comparing between Node und Bun and the results are very mixed. Complex tasks like a huge Webpack project resulted in Node being 10% faster than Bun and express based servers resulted in Bun being 50% faster than Node.
As always: it depends!
What I actually like the most with Bun is btw how easy it is to run TypeScript code ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is true. BunJS is actually faster than NodeJS. I wrote a tree-walk interpreter in JavaScript and ran it using both Node and BunJS. NodeJS took ~1 seconds were as Bun took ~0.73s the first time and even less the second time:

[image: test run for node and bun]

In this case, the increase is not much as the code was already quite optimised but for a server, Bun can be exponentially faster.